Asymmetric key encryption and decryption using js and python
I am trying to include asymmetric encryption . The logic is:
Python (flask) generates public and private key. the public key is sent to js. js encrypts the message and sends it back to the python flask backend. the backend now decrypts the key.
The problem is this isn't working. The error I am receiving is:

The key length should be equal to ciphertext

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5

def encrypt(public_key, plaintext):
# Deserialize the public key
public_key_obj = serialization.load_pem_public_key(public_key)

    # Encrypt the plaintext using the public key
    ciphertext = public_key_obj.encrypt(
        plaintext.encode(),
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return ciphertext

def decrypt(private_key, ciphertext):
# Load the private key
private_key_obj = serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key, password=None)

    # Initialize the cipher with the private key
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key_obj)
    
    # Decrypt the ciphertext
    decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, None)
    
    return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')

def generate_keypair():
# Generate RSA key pair
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537,key_size=2048)
public_key = private_key.public_key()

    # Serialize private key to PEM format
    pem_private_key = private_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )
    
    # Serialize public key to PEM format
    pem_public_key = public_key.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    )
    
    return pem_private_key, pem_public_key
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    private_key, public_key = generate_keypair()

    # Encrypted data received from JavaScript
    encrypted_data_from_js = "..."  # Insert the encrypted data received from JavaScript
    
    # Decode the base64 encoded encrypted data
    encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_data_from_js)
    
    # Decrypt the encrypted data
    decrypted_data = decrypt(private_key, encrypted_data)
    
    print("Decrypted message:", decrypted_data)

My flask code:
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    private_key,public_key = generate_keypair()
    print(private_key,":",public_key)
    form = LoginForm()
    if session.get('username'):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('login.html', error_message='Not Authorised',public_key=public_key)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        encrpassword = form.password.data
        print(f"{username}:{encrpassword}")
        password = decrypt(private_key=private_key, ciphertext=encrpassword.encode())
        print(f'username {username} password {password}')
        access, role = get_user_access_privilege(username)

My Javascript code:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsencrypt/3.3.2/jsencrypt.js"></script>
<script>
    var encryptor = new JSEncrypt();
    function encryptAndSubmit() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var publicKey = "{{ public_key }}"; // Public key from Python

        // Set the public key
        encryptor.setPublicKey(publicKey);

        // Encrypt the password using OAEP with SHA-256
        var encryptedPassword = encryptor.encrypt(password, 'sha256');
        alert(encryptedPassword);

        // Update the password field with the encrypted password
        document.getElementById("password").value = btoa(encryptedPassword);

        // Submit the form
        document.getElementById("LoginForm").submit();
    }

    // Call the function when the form is submitted
    document.getElementById("LoginForm").addEventListener("submit", encryptAndSubmit);
</script>
```

error:
ValueError
ValueError: Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.


The "error [you're] receiving" doesn't appear in any other Google-able site except on this page. Do you mind updating your post so it includes a direct copy/paste of the error message and stack trace you're actually seeing? Can you also update your snippets such that they constitute a proper [mre]? There is a bit of code context missing in your JavaScript snippet (i.e., what is encryptor, and why doesn't it require any configuration of the algorithm you're using?)? Have you verified that your template replacement {{ public_key }} is functioning the way you intend?

yes {{public_key}} seems to be working. I have updated the js. encryptor is an instance of JSEncrypt()

I am curious, why do you need this? This is exactly what https is doing for you, if you use it.

I have https on it but when testing, the contents sent over is easily viewable by tracing the network or using burp suit hence I want to protect it from the vulnerability

No, SSL-encrypted contents (i.e. https protocol traffic) should not be easily viewable, or the whole Internet shopping/banking would be dead by now. No reputable site uses home-baked encryption, everyone trusts SSL. If you are testing on http, which does make sense, it would be viewable, but you should be using nonce data, not production data, or else you should be using a closed local network that you control; implementing your own crypto solution just so you don't have to use SSL is very, very weird.
